# Creating a monotonous rising function that is not equivalent to a continuous function on any interval

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, continuity

I have the answer given. I do not understand only one step in it.

$\mathbb Q$ is countable, so therefore we can put it's points in a array: 
$\{q_0,q_1,...\}$

and then the function $$f(x)=\sum_{\forall n,q_n<x}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

this is monotonuous: $$x_1<x_2,f(x_1)-f(x_2)=\sum_{\forall n,x_1<q_n<x_2}\frac{1}{n^2}>0$$

Now we take $x \in \mathcal I$ and prove that is indeed continuous in $x$.

We use : $$\omega_\delta(f(x))=\sup_{x_1,x_2 \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)}|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|$$ A function is continuous at point $x$ when $$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\omega_{\delta}(f(x))=0$$

Then:
$$\omega_\delta(f(x))=\sup_{x_1<x_2 \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)}|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|=\sup_{x_1<x_2 \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)}\sum_{\forall n,x_1<q_n<x_2}\frac{1}{n^2}(*)$$

This is what is unclear to me: **We can choose **  $\delta$ **small enough, such that**  $q_1,q_2,...,q_N \notin(x-\delta,x+\delta)$

So $$(*)\leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \to^{n\to \infty}=0$$ (the equality is clear, the inequality not at all. Can someone explain this idea to me?) Also this choose of $\delta?   $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_N\}$ is finite, and $x$ is not in this set, since $x$ is irrational. Thus, $|x-q_k|>0$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$, and we can set

$$\delta=\min\{|x-q_k|:k=1,\ldots,N\}>0\;:$$

the minimum of a finite set of positive numbers exists and is finite.

Suppose that $q_j\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for some $j$; then $|x-q_j|<\delta\le|x-q_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$, so $j>N$. Thus, $q_k\notin(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$. This means that if $x_1,x_2\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, and $x_1<x_2$, then

$$\{n:x_1<q_n<x_2\}\subseteq\{n:q_n\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\}\subseteq\{n:n>N\}\;,$$

and hence

$$\sum_{x_1<q_n<x_2}\frac1{n^2}\le\sum_{n>N}\frac1{n^2}\;.$$

This is true for every subinterval $(x_1,x_2)$ of $x-\delta,x+\delta)$, so

$$\sup_{(x_1,x_2)\subseteq(x-\delta,x+\delta)}\;\sum_{x_1<q_n<x_2}\frac1{n^2}\le\sum_{n>N}\frac1{n^2}$$

as well.